# Identify ckeditor textarea id for blur event

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have plenty of textareas which act as a `CKEDITOR 4`. I'm trying to perform the AJAX request on each textarea by blur event. I know how to do the `blur` event. but the problem is how can I get the `ckeditor` instance (textarea id) to get the data. I found this question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831705/how-to-trigger-the-blur-event-on-ckeditor-textareas) and I tried but it doesn't help me. also I tried like below method but no luck
This is how I'm making all the textareas into ckeditor

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
CKEDITOR.inline( this,{toolbar:[{ name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },{ name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat','Undo' ] },{ name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList' ] }]})
})
```

This below portion works well for particular id

```
CKEDITOR.instances.releaset44.on('blur', function() { 
  alert("save fun")
});
```

above codes are inside the `body onload` function. below code is in outside of the `onload` func. please correct me if I'm wrong

```
 var editors = CKEDITOR.instances;

    for (var x in editors) {
          if (editors[x]) {
            var thisName = editors[x].name;
            alert(thisName)
            if (editors[thisName]) {
              editors[thisName].on('blur', function (e) {
                var data = e.editor.getData();
              alert(data)
              });
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Does editors[thisName] return a DOM selector?

Comment: No I didn't get any of the alert over there

Comment: Can't you find the id of the element in the element tree of Chrome inspector?

Comment: you mean the textarea id? if yes the id is release43

Comment: Can you show the entire json object that CKEDITOR.instances returns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203343/discussion-between-trace-and-aroon).

Comment: Finally it is working. thanks @Trace. The answer is wrap the blur function inside the body onload function